# How do you get the "Contacts" app "Birthday" field look in Android 7.1?

Tags: android, material-design, spinner, android-spinner, android-7.1-nougat

We're trying to get a field to look like the "Date" field on the "Create new contact" screen of the "Contacts" app. We can't figure out if that's a Spinner, a Button, an EditText or how to get that behavior without reinventing the wheel.

We tried:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
        android:id="@+id/le_spinner"
        style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:prompt="@string/date_prompt"
        android:spinnerMode="dialog"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="none"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <TextView
        style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Select"/>

    <Button
        style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Select"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

None of the outcomes is the same as the one in the "Contacts" app (see below):

[image: "Contacts" app]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the "Date" field is a Button, most likely styled with `style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"`.

We took the following steps to determine that:

- We ran our app in the emulator;
- We switched to the "Contacts" app;
- We navigated to the "Create new contact" activity (after adding an account to the "Contacts" app);
- We switched to the "Android Monitor" tool window, selected the "com.android.contacts" app in the filter at the top of that window, then clicked the "Layout Inspector" button;
- We were prompted to select a window/activity, and we selected "com.android.contacts.activities.CompactContactEditorActivity", then "OK";
- We got the information we were looking for like in the image below:

[image]